# TypeError when trying to extend session.user object using AuthJS

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

Im trying to extend the session.user object by follow the example code in official docs but a type error raised. Here is my code:

```
import "next-auth";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth";

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface User {
    group: string;
    avatar: string;
  }
}

export const config = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signin",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: "Email (@mobifone.vn)",
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const authResponse = await fetch(
          "http://localhost:9000/api/v1/auth/signin",
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
              username: credentials.email,
              password: credentials.password,
            }),
          }
        );

        if (!authResponse.ok) {
          return null;
        }

        const res = await authResponse.json();

        return res.user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      // session.user.address is now a valid property, and will be type-checked
      // in places like `useSession().data.user` or `auth().user`
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          group: user.group,
          avatar: user.avatar,
        },
      };
    },
  },
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(config);
```

The error message found in session callback said that

```
Type '({ session, token, user }: { session: Session; token: JWT; user: AdapterUser; } & { newSession: any; trigger: "update"; }) => Promise<{ user: { group: string; avatar: string; id?: string | undefined; name?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; email?: string | ... 1 more ... | undefined; image?: string | ... 1 more ...' is not assignable to type '(params: { session: Session; token: JWT; user: AdapterUser; } & { newSession: any; trigger: "update"; }) => Awaitable<Session | DefaultSession>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ user: { group: string; avatar: string; id?: string | undefined; name?: string | null | undefined; email?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; }; expires: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'Awaitable<Session | DefaultSession>'.
    Type 'Promise<{ user: { group: string; avatar: string; id?: string | undefined; name?: string | null | undefined; email?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; }; expires: string; }>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<Session | DefaultSession>'.
      Types of property 'then' are incompatible.
        Type '<TResult1 = { user: { group: string; avatar: string; id?: string | undefined; name?: string | null | undefined; email?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; }; expires: string; }, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: { ...; }) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 more ... | undefined,...' is not assignable to type '<TResult1 = Session | DefaultSession, TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: Session | DefaultSession) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | ... 1 more ... | undefined) => PromiseLike<...>'.
          Types of parameters 'onfulfilled' and 'onfulfilled' are incompatible.
            Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
              Type '{ user: { group: string; avatar: string; id?: string | undefined; name?: string | null | undefined; email?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; }; expires: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Session | DefaultSession'.
                Type '{ user: { group: string; avatar: string; id?: string | undefined; name?: string | null | undefined; email?: string | null | undefined; image?: string | null | undefined; }; expires: string; }' is not assignable to type 'DefaultSession'.
                  The types of 'user.id' are incompatible between these types.
                    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
                      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

I really dont understand this. Please help.

I tried to add id to user object inside session callback like this:

```
callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      // session.user.address is now a valid property, and will be type-checked
      // in places like `useSession().data.user` or `auth().user`
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: user.id,
          group: user.group,
          avatar: user.avatar,
        },
      };
    },
  },
```

but it just hiding the error message, I cant login with this config.